# How to overwrite __getattribute__() in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to modify `__getattribute__()` method for an instance, as you may already know, `__getattirbute__` is read-only attribute in Python (edit: appereantly, for some objects it is, and for others it isn't). What I have in mind is, create a new object like this:

```
def create_new_instace(old_instance):
    class temp(old_instance.__class__):
        def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
            "Since we will copy an already inited instance"
            pass
        def __getattribute__(self,attr):
           # do stuff
    new_instance = temp()
    # magically copy all attrs of old_instance to new_instance
    return new_instance
```

Is this kind of thing possible? I am not having a particular problem, I just want to know how to do this.

Comment: If you tell us more about the problem you are having, and the larger goal of the system, you might get more detailed help.

Comment: Readonlyability of an attribute depends on `__setattribute__` method

Answer (score 2):

Actually, yes. Check difference between `__getattribute__` and `__getattr__` method [here](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html)

You can assign new value to the instance's field `__getattribute__` except if `__setattr__` explicitly prohibits that. Try this in your python prompt:

```
>>>class A(object):
>>>    pass
>>>A().__getattribute__ = myFunc
>>>A().__getattr__ = myFunc
```

If the `__setattr__` won't allow you to do so, you have to do something like solution you proposed. Check module `copy` for 'magically copying' attributes.

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to use copy module with my purpose. Can you provide some example code please?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible for Python 2.2+, just the way you attempt it, read here (search for **getattirbute**) for the specific things you should take into consideration:
http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.2/descrintro/

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand your goal. If you simply want to create a new object that is a duplicate of another object, you can use

```
from copy import copy
new_instance = copy( old_instance )
```

This creates a shallow copy. There is also `copy.deepcopy` for deep copies of objects.

If you want a derived class that has a copy of another instances attributes (an possibly other customizations, that you need to make dynamically for some reason), you can use:

```
from copy import copy
def create_new_instance( old_instance ):
    class NewClass( old_instance.__class__ ):
        """
        dynamic custom class
        """
        # ... customizations

    new_instance = copy( old_instance )
    new_instance.__class__ = NewClass
```

This won't work for some system class types, for which `__class__` isn't assignable. (e.g. list, tuple, str, I think).

In these cases you can define your derived class with `__new__` ... but I'm not sure if there is a "standard" way to define the arguments -- you might be reduced to going through cases.

Note that unless you have other reasons for creating the new class dynamically, you needn't define it inside your function.